# 1 to 1 Relationship, Optional on both sides in EF Code First

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6

This question keeps popping up, but I couldn't find anyone doing exactly what I am, so here goes:

I've got a table that can have a relationship to one of many tables. Some have many, and some have one. In all cases it would be optional.

So we have a table of Pictures.

We have Products, Vendors, Users.

Products have a one to many relationship with Pictures (they can upload multiple photos of each product).
Users have a one to one (optional on both sides) with pictures. (If the user uploads a photo, great, if not, no problem)
Vendors have a one to one, similar to Users, except it is relating to a different table.

This works fine with the many relationships, but the one to one doesn't work properly.

I want to have a virtual on both sides but define the nullable ForeignKey only in the Pictures table.

```
public virtual Picture UserPhoto { get; set; }
```

And then on the other side:

```
public virtual User User{ get; set; }
[ForeignKey("User")]
public int? UserID { get; set; }
```

I like to have the keys available in the code, not just in the database, so I don't want to configure the relationship solely in fluent. But If I add a fluent configuration on top, it will add extra foreign keys.

Without a fluent configuration, we get the dreaded

> Multiplicity is not valid in Role 'Picture_User_Source' in relationship 'Picture_User'. Because the Dependent Role properties are not the key properties, the upper bound of the multiplicity of the Dependent Role must be '*'.

Comment: you force use fluent api for set this.

Comment: Which configuration would create the correct Foreign Keys? Right now I am just leaving it as a one to many because that has the same database structure that I want. The downside is having a collection instead of a reference property.

Comment: see this link : http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2011/04/24/associations-in-ef-4-1-code-first-part-4-table-splitting.aspx

Comment: Are you saying it should be set as required on both ends? This relationship is not required for either entity. Because the same entity (Picture) can be associated with a user OR a vendor, neither the UserID nor the VendorID is required.